# Looping along named ranges in VBA with a hidden =true/false output for the range itself, not the data within the range

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have named a number of columns as ranges e.g.
DesCond1, DesDiff1, Comparison1, DesCond2, DesDiff2, Etc...
I have some buttons which use a macro to toggle the different columns visible or hidden. I have added the code I am using for one of these buttons.
Currently I have written the code to show or hide each range individually but I would like a code that will count the number of ranges with a similar name (DesCond1, DesCond2.. DesCond(n))and then loop through each one automatically checking the hidden status so I don't have to add to the code everytime I add more data. Here is my code so far. This works fine so far.

```
Sub ComparisonToggle1()
Dim ComparisonAll As Range, R_Cond As Range, R_Diff As Range

'set first of each range as identifier for decisions
Set R_Comp = Range("Comparison1")

'set all ranges under one name
Set CompAll = Union(Range("Comparison1"), Range("Comparison2"), Range("Comparison3")) 'name and add when new tests are added

If R_Comp.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then           'False
    CompAll.EntireColumn.Hidden = True                  'hide all
ElseIf R_Comp.EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then        'True
    CompAll.EntireColumn.Hidden = False                 'vis all
End If

End Sub
```

```
Sub DesignToggle1()
Dim DesCondAll As Range, DesDiffAll As Range, R_Cond As Range, R_Diff As Range

'set first of each range as identifier for decisions
Set R_Cond = Range("DesCond1")
Set R_Diff = Range("DesDiff1")

'set all ranges under one name
Set DesCondAll = Union(Range("DesCond1"), Range("DesCond2"), Range("DesCond3"), Range("DesCond4"), Range("DesCond5"), Range("DesCond6")) 'name and add when new tests are added
Set DesDiffAll = Union(Range("DesDiff1"), Range("DesDiff2"), Range("DesDiff3"), Range("DesDiff4"), Range("DesDiff5"), Range("DesDiff6")) 'name and add when new tests are added


If R_Cond.EntireColumn.Hidden = False And R_Diff.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then           'False/False
    DesCondAll.EntireColumn.Hidden = True                                                       'both hidden
    DesDiffAll.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ElseIf R_Cond.EntireColumn.Hidden = True And R_Diff.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then        'True/False
    DesCondAll.EntireColumn.Hidden = False                                                      'vis both
    DesDiffAll.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
ElseIf R_Cond.EntireColumn.Hidden = False And R_Diff.EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then        'False/True
    DesCondAll.EntireColumn.Hidden = False                                                      'vis both
    DesDiffAll.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
ElseIf R_Cond.EntireColumn.Hidden = True And R_Diff.EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then         'True/True
    DesCondAll.EntireColumn.Hidden = False                                                      'vis both
    DesDiffAll.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you going to feed the macro which group do you want to hide each time?

Comment: For example:Use a description like "DesCond*" so it loops through all named ranges with that and a number at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to loop through all the names in your workbook, thought you need to give it the group you want to filter:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test(Group As String)

    Dim MyName As Name
    For Each MyName In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If MyName.Name Like "*" & Group & "*" Then
            Range(MyName).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next MyName

End Sub
Sub Main()

    'This procedure calls the Test procedure feeding the variable Group as "Descond"
    Test "Descond"

End Sub
```

Comment: what does this code do:
'If MyName.Name Like "*2" & Group & "*" Then'

Comment: @JadeySwan-McCay  to filter the ranged name... in your example `Group` would be `DesCond`. This loop would iterate through all the named ranges, but will execute the code only to the ones which contain `DesCond`. The 2 is a typo though.

Comment: So I would use `group = "DesCond"` In the code somewhere? ... What code would I use to then hide these ranges. I can't use `MyName.EntireColumn.Hidden = True`.... How would I change this to a range selection?

Comment: `MyName` is a `Name` variable,  not a range, so you can't perform with it as you would with a range. You can use `Range(MyName).EntireColumn.Hidden = True` instead @JadeySwan-McCay. As for how to call this, it would be like my edit.